# mocha test route, req.session.code is undefined

Tags: node.js, session, mocha.js

I want to test two routers, first generates a verification code, and keep in req.session.code, the second check the code.
routers:

```
`router.post('/code', (req, res) = > {
   let text = generateCode();
   req.session.code = text;
   res.json({message: text}); 
 })`

`router.post('/check_code' , (req, res) => {
   let c = req.body.code;
   console.log(c, req.session.code) //when test, req.session.code is undefined
   if (c.toUpperCase() !== req.session.code.toUpperCase()) {
      return res.json('error');
   }
   return res.json('ok');
})`
```

then, I use `supertest` and `mocha` test.

```
`describe('test', function() {
   let code; //check code as body
   it('get verification code', function(done) {
     request.agent(app)
        .post('/code')
        .expect(200)
        .end(function(err, res){
         if (err) return done(err);
         code = res.body.message;
          done();
      })
   })
   it('check verification code', function(done) {
     request.agent(app)
        .post('/check_code')
        .send({code: code}) 
        .expect(200)
        .end(function(err, res){
         if (err) return done(err);
         code = res.body.message;
          done();
      })
   })
})`
```

the first passing, the second failing, and I test manually with postMan, it works, I printed the req.session:

```
`session {
  cookie:
   {path: '/',
    _expires:null,
    originalMaxAge: null,
    httpOnly: true
   },
   code: xxxx  //there is code when use postMan,but not in mocha
}`
```

and I hava used .agent in my code, but it does`t work. so how should I do to test router when some values keep in session? I hava not found the same question yet.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a new agent for each test, but you need *one* agent to use across the tests if you want the agent to support cookies properly (because the agent stores received cookies internally, and subsequent requests made with the same agent will use those cookies):

```
describe('test', function() {
   let agent = request.agent(app);
   let code; //check code as body

   it('get verification code', function(done) {
     agent.post('/code')...
   });

   it('check verification code', function(done) {
     agent.post('/code')...
   });

});
```